# Allow listing virtual directory among others in IIS

Tags: iis-7, virtual-directory

I have a folder with two physical directories:

```
myfolder
   foo
   bar
```

And I map a virtual directory into `myfolder/baz`.

When I access the directory listing for `myfolder`, only `foo` and `bar` are shown. I know this is by design, but is it possible at all to allow virtual directories be listed among physical ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to accomplish this.

You have to create an empty folder with the same name (`baz` in my example). It will make that folder appear among other physical folders in the directory listing and will display contents from virtual directory mapped to the same folder.

Hopefully this will help someone else.